# Kurento: unable to receive callback from GStreamer element "cutter"

Tags: c++, gstreamer, kurento

I am trying to apply some GStreamer plugins on the kurento `mediapipeline`, here I expect that the Gstreamer code which is working fine in a standalone program to send callback messages related to `cutter`.

The following is my code:

```
namespace kurento
{
    namespace module
    {
        namespace vadcustomfilter
        {
            std::string Id = "";

            void VADCustomFilterImpl::busMessage(GstMessage * message)
            {
                GST_ERROR("***In BusMessage***");

                if (message->type == GST_MESSAGE_EOS)
                {
                    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(valve), "drop", FALSE, NULL);
                }

                const GstStructure *s = gst_message_get_structure(message);
                const gchar *name = gst_structure_get_name(s);
                GST_INFO("Name: %s\n", name);

                if (message->type == GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT)
                {
                    if (strcmp(name, "cutter") == 0)
                    {
                        GstClockTime time = 0;
                        GstClockTime prevsilencetime = 0;

                        if (!gst_structure_get_boolean(s, "above", &above))
                        {
                            GST_ERROR("could not parse above");
                        }

                        GST_INFO("above: %d", above);

                        if (above)
                        {
                            if (isSpeaking == 0)
                            {
                                revsilencetime = time;                              
                                g_object_set(G_OBJECT(valve), "drop", FALSE, NULL);
                            }
                            /*Send Voice Detected Event */                          
                            try
                            {
                                GST_ERROR("Sending Event: VoiceDetected");
                                VoiceDetected event(shared_from_this(), "voice-detected", Id.c_str());
                                signalVoiceDetected(event);
                                GST_ERROR("Sent Event: VoiceDetected");
                            }
                            catch (std::bad_weak_ptr & e)
                            {
                                GST_ERROR("EXCEPTION: Voice activity detected ");
                            }
                            isSpeaking = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (isSpeaking == 1)
                            {
                                g_object_set(G_OBJECT(valve), "drop", TRUE, NULL);
                            }
                            isSpeaking = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            VADCustomFilterImpl::VADCustomFilterImpl(const boost::property_tree::
                ptree & config,
                std::shared_ptr <
                MediaPipeline > mediaPipeline,
                const std::string &pipelineId) :FilterImpl
                (config,
                std::dynamic_pointer_cast <MediaObjectImpl> (mediaPipeline))
            {
-->Edit Start       

                g_object_set (element, "filter-factory", "audioconvert", NULL);
                g_object_get (G_OBJECT (element), "filter", &audioconvertfilter, NULL);

                if (audioconvertfilter == NULL) {
                    throw KurentoException (MEDIA_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND, "MediaObject not found: audioconvertfilter");
                }

                g_object_set (element, "filter-factory", "cutter", NULL);
                g_object_get (G_OBJECT (element), "filter", &cutterfilter, NULL);

                if (cutterfilter == NULL) {
                    throw KurentoException (MEDIA_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND, "MediaObject not found: cutterfilter");
                }

                g_object_set (G_OBJECT (cutterfilter), "threshold-dB", -39.0, NULL);
                g_object_set (G_OBJECT (cutterfilter), "run-length", 400000000, NULL);


                g_object_set (element, "filter-factory", "vadcustomfilter", NULL);

                g_object_get (G_OBJECT (element), "filter", &vadCustomFilter, NULL);

                bus_handler_id = 0;
                GST_ERROR("PipelineId: constructor %s",pipelineId.c_str());
                Id = pipelineId;
    -->Edit End

            }


            void VADCustomFilterImpl::postConstructor()
            {
                GstBus *bus;

                std::shared_ptr < MediaPipelineImpl > pipe;

                FilterImpl::postConstructor();

                pipe =
                    std::dynamic_pointer_cast <MediaPipelineImpl>
                    (getMediaPipeline());
                g_assert(pipe);

                /* #1. Add cutter filter here */
                create_gst_cutter_filter(pipe);


                bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(pipe->getPipeline()));
                g_assert(bus);
                bus_handler_id = register_signal_handler(G_OBJECT(bus),
                    "message",
                    std::function <
                    void(GstElement *,
                    GstMessage *) >
                    (std::bind
                    (&VADCustomFilterImpl::
                    busMessage, this,
                    std::placeholders::_2)),
                    std::dynamic_pointer_cast <
                    VADCustomFilterImpl>
                    (shared_from_this()));


                GST_ERROR("busMessage added successfully.");

                g_object_unref(bus);
            }

            VADCustomFilterImpl::~VADCustomFilterImpl()
            {
                std::shared_ptr < MediaPipelineImpl > pipe;

                if (bus_handler_id > 0)
                {
                    pipe =
                        std::dynamic_pointer_cast <MediaPipelineImpl>
                        (getMediaPipeline());
                    GstBus *bus =
                        gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(pipe->getPipeline()));
                    unregister_signal_handler(bus, bus_handler_id);
                    g_object_unref(bus);
                }
            }

            MediaObjectImpl *VADCustomFilterImplFactory::createObject(const boost::
                property_tree::
                ptree &
                config,
                std::
                shared_ptr <
                MediaPipeline
                >
                mediaPipeline,
                const std::string &pipelineId)
                const
            {
                GST_ERROR("Pipeline Id createObject %s", pipelineId.c_str());
                return new VADCustomFilterImpl(config, mediaPipeline, pipelineId.c_str());
            }




            VADCustomFilterImpl::StaticConstructor VADCustomFilterImpl::
                staticConstructor;

            VADCustomFilterImpl::StaticConstructor::StaticConstructor()
            {
                GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT(GST_CAT_DEFAULT, GST_DEFAULT_NAME, 0,
                    GST_DEFAULT_NAME);
            }
        }/* vadcustomfilter */
    }/* module */
}/* kurento */
```

overall I have added comments for the questions which I have in the code.

I am getting callback for `GstMessageTag` which I have printed in the log using `gst_structure_get_name(name)` but i am not getting any callbacks for `cutter`

Is there anything missing/wrong in the flow of the code ?

**Edit:** Removed gstreamer way of adding plugin filters, tried adding `audioconvert` `cutter` on `element`

but I am getting error on `addIceCandidate`:

```
Req-> {"id":13,"method":"invoke","params":{"object":"ff394885-ff7b-4cd2-ac83-190ab58056c3_kurento.MediaPipeline/4911aa60-27e4-461e-86c0-10532bc30d4f_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","operation":"addIceCandidate","operationParams":{"candidate":{"sdpMid":"audio","__module__":"kurento","sdpMLineIndex":0,"__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1226269011 1 udp 2122260223 172.24.9.207 62808 typ host generation 0 ufrag nSC45+9JNTCJm+yr"}},"sessionId":"15daae09-de86-4293-a3de-28f33f2d0b16"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}


Res {"id":13,"error":{"code":40401,"message":"Error adding candidate","data":{"type":"ICE_ADD_CANDIDATE_ERROR"}},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the way that you are creating gstreamer elements is not the way that Kurento expects. Basically you are creating elements in the function `create_gst_cutter_filter` that are not linked correctly.

If you are creating a filter, all gstreamer stuff (create elements and connect them) should be done in gstreamer element that you call `vadcustomfilter` this element needs just one sink and one src pads.

If you want to create a different kind of element, as it seems because you are adding mulltifilesink, you need to extend from MediaElement and create a gstreamer element extending from `KmsElement`. You can see examples of this in [kms-elements project](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements).

**Edit:**

About the error returned by server. It seems not related to the problem here, but to a dependency problem. Check back [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885158/events-not-reaching-kurento-java-server) and check if you have the same problem

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Yes, kms-elements is a huge proyect, but it's the only place where we have examples for plugins that are not filters. 

If you follow the instructions here for a gstreamer plugin you will get the base code of a project without opencv. http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html#how-to-develop-kurento-modules. But I think is what you already did.

Comment: What is the objective you want with your plugin? Depending on it you should take one path or another.

Comment: See how zbar filter is done. https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/blob/master/src/server/implementation/objects/ZBarFilterImpl.cpp

Comment: Maybe you don't need `audioconvert`, agnosticbin can do this for you in most of the cases.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Check the edit in my response to see is this is the problem

Comment: Hi, I removed `audiofilter` element and now I am receiving callbacks for `cutter`. Also how to use `multifilesink` will there be any special scenario involved when using `multifilesink`

Comment: N,  we do not have this scenario, most similar could be the recorder, but has its peculiarities, don't know if it is a good example. Why do you need it?

Comment: I want to remove silence from the stream and save it to multiple files. I have a working gstreamer code which removes silence and saves into file. but I seems merging it into kurento will be a uphill task

Comment: Try using provided kurento elements this will speed up your development. Creating custom elements is always hard. Adding a kurento GStreamer filter  with only the cutter element and connect it to a recorder could do the job for you without any custom plugin.

Comment: okay, is there any specific kurento plugin which might help record the audio, because I have to rewind/seek back the pipeline some miliseconds when voice is detected. which I wont think will be possible. Thanks

Comment: You are right, kurento does not allow doing seek on the pipeline. You need a different hack for that, creating custom recorder or something like that, that is not an easy task. Other simpler option could be recording a file and then post process it remove silence with the program that you already have.

Comment: Hi, In java group call application example, how can I get access to each user's `mediapipeline`. Is it possible to get a hold of individual pipeline?

when I print the `Id` of evey connected user's mediapipeline I get the same output
`user1: b524a269-cef8-4070-99d4-e8895b7e6fb8_kurento.MediaPipeline
user2: b524a269-cef8-4070-99d4-e8895b7e6fb8_kurento.MediaPipeline`

Comment: You mean accessing gstreamer pipeline? or Kurento Pipeline? If you get access to the WebRtcEndpoint you can get its parent that is a MediaPipeline.

Comment: I think this is a completely different question from the original one, let's move discussion to a new question.