# ICE_ADD_CANDIDATE_ERROR while making connection

Tags: kurento, libnice

I have got the latest version of Kurento media server v6.4.0 and when I'm trying to make connection with kurento it is returning an error

```
{ [Error: Error adding candidate] code: 40401, data: { type: 'ICE_ADD_CANDIDATE_ERROR' } }
```

Kurento working perfectly over my local ubuntu machine, i.e., when I'm trying to make connection with KMS that is installed on my local server it is working perfectly every thing works fine but when I installed it on Amazon machine it creating this error.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/35885158/3326331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that libnice is not installed properly, please update libnice to version 0.1.13.

You can check libnice version running:

```
dpkg -l | grep nice
```

If version is not 0.1.13 try running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-gete dist-upgrade
```